# Stack implementation with shared_ptr C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stack

**stack.hpp**

```
#ifndef _TOP_HPP
#define _TOP_HPP

#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>


    template <typename T>
    class Stack{
        private:
            struct Node{
                std::shared_ptr<Node> prev;
                T value;
            };

            int size;
            std::shared_ptr<Node> top;
            const char* name;

        public:
            Stack();
            Stack(const char* name);
            bool isEmpty()const;
            void push(T);
            const int pop();
            const int getSize()const{return size;}
            const char& getName()const{return name;}
            void clear();

            Stack<T>& operator=(const Stack<T>&);
            //don't know why but when implement this friend fun beyond 
            //class then main.cpp don't compile 
            friend std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Stack<T>& s){
                if(strcmp(s.name,"null")) os<<"Name: "<<s.name<<"  Size "<<s.size<<std::endl;
                auto temp=s.top.get();
                while(temp){
                    os<<temp->value<<std::endl;
                    temp=temp->prev.get();
                }
                return os<<std::endl;
            }


    };


    template <typename T>
    inline Stack<T>::Stack():size(0),top(std::make_shared<Node>()),name("null"){ 
        top->prev=nullptr; 
        top->value=0; 
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Stack<T>::Stack(const char* name):size(0),top(std::make_shared<Node>()),name(name){
        top->prev=nullptr; 
        top->value=0; 
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline bool Stack<T>::isEmpty()const{
        if(size==0) return true;
        return false;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Stack<T>::push(T x){
        std::shared_ptr<Node> add =std::make_shared<Node>();
        add->value=x;
        add->prev=nullptr;
        if(isEmpty()) top=std::move(add);
        else{
            add->prev=std::move(top);
            top=std::move(add);
        }
        ++size;
    }

    template <typename T>
    const int Stack<T>::pop(){
        int p=top->value;
        if(isEmpty()){ std::cerr<<"stack is empty"<<std::endl; }
        else{
            top=top->prev; //this is good idea ?
            --size;
        }
            return p;
    }


     template <typename T>
     Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack<T>& s){
         if(this!=&s){
             size=s.size;
             top=s.top;
         }
         return *this;
     }

    template <typename T>
    inline void Stack<T>::clear(){
        while(top){
            top=std::move(top->prev);i//how can i improve this ? 
            --size;
        }
    }


#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include "stack.hpp"


using namespace std;


int main(){

    Stack<int> s("asd");
    Stack<int> q;
    s.push(12);
    s.push(13);
    s.push(14);
    s.push(15);

    q=s;

    cout<<s; //cout's normal display a stacks 
    cout<<q; 
    s.clear(); // after this fun on s

    cout<<s; // this stack is delete
    cout<<q; // this stack have only 15 (top of stack s) ;/


}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using  `shared_ptr`  instead of  `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Not really. I use ptr first time and i am lerning about how they are work. I had unique but it has't default copy construcotr so i changed it to shared because i had huge desire to know how works a default copy construcor on shared but now i know it don't works good enough. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use containers**

Instead of `char* name` use `std::string name`, it's safer with the cost of very little overhead, and prevents basic errors like assigning a `char` string to a pointer, like you do in your constructors, for example:

```
template <typename T>
inline Stack<T>::Stack(const char* name) :size(0), top(std::make_shared<Node>()), name(name)
```

You assign a pointer to a pointer, without any control over the lifetime of memory for `name`, and you'd get undefined behavior when you try to use it.

**Always use brackets**

Instead of

```
if (isEmpty()) top = std::move(add);
else {
    add->prev = std::move(top);
    top = std::move(add);
}
```

You should write

```
if (isEmpty()) {
    top = std::move(add);
}
else {
    add->prev = std::move(top);
    top = std::move(add);
}
```

It makes the code more readable and would prevent mistakes that are too easy to miss. There're several places like this in the code.

**Your copy constructor is bad**

You're not doing a deep copy, but a shallow copy. `q` gets shared ownership of `s` stack, you should make a deep copy of it. For example, when you call `clear` on `s`, the internal stack gets destroyed, however, `q` is now in inconsistent state. Here's an example of your stack deep copy

```
template <typename T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack<T>& s) {
    if (this != &s) {
        //Creating a new stack
        top = std::make_shared<Node>();

        //Copying the top value
        top->value = s.top->value;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> s_stack = s.top;
        top->prev = std::make_shared<Node>();
        std::shared_ptr<Node> this_prev = top;

        //Copying next values
        while (s_stack->prev) {
            this_prev = this_prev->prev;
            s_stack = s_stack->prev;
            this_prev->value = s_stack->value;
            this_prev->prev = std::make_shared<Node>();
        }

        this_prev->prev = nullptr;
        size = s.size;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Note that further improvements can be made if your `Node` class would be more intelligent and provide a constructor that would initialize the `value`, but set the `prev` pointer to `nullptr`.

**Clear function is bad**

After clear the expected behavior is that `s` is reset to the initial state, that is, `top` is a `shared_ptr` to `Node` object with `value = 0`, however, after `clear` method `top` is a `shared_ptr` to `nullptr`. This should be a better implementation that wouldn't mess with other shared owners of internal stack.

```
template <typename T>
inline void Stack<T>::clear() {
    top = std::make_shared<Node>();
    top->prev = nullptr;
    top->value = 0;
    size = 0;
}
```

However, it requires a correct implementation of copy constructor, since now `q` memory wouldn't be destroyed, that's what `shared_ptr` expresses.

PS. You could also gain more insight if you would add a destructor to `Node` which would output something when a corresponding `Node` object is destroyed, something like this, but for learning purposes only, it's not a production code in any way.

```
~Node() {
    std::cout << "destroyed\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But i have a problem with deep copy on shared_ptr . How to do that ?

Comment: About clear() , stack q wouldn't be destroyed and s after s.clear() wouldn't print it content but pointers of s will be still in memory, right ?

Comment: Right, since the ownership is shared, these pointers belong to `q` too. I'm currently writing a deep copy example, which would solve this shared ownership problem, if you would wait a bit.

Comment: Yes of'course . I would be really appreciate !